# Installing Jupyter nbextensions Error

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

I'm trying to install nbextensions for Jupyter Notebooks but I keep getting the error.  I have tried reinstalling Anaconda3 without any success and updating both pip and conda.

```
C:\Windows\System32>jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kai\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\kai\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\kai\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-contrib.EXE\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\kai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\kai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 656, in launch_instance
    app = cls.instance(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\kai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\kai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_contrib_core\application.py", line 27, in __init__
    self._refresh_subcommands()
  File "c:\users\kai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_contrib_core\application.py", line 43, in _refresh_subcommands
    get_subcommands_dict = entrypoint.load()
  File "c:\users\kai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2404, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\kai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2427, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
  File "c:\users\kai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 872, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (jupyter-core 4.3.0 (c:\users\kai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('jupyter_core>=4.4.0'), {'notebook'})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by downgrading to Jupyter Notebook 5.2.1 from 5.3.1